# What does it mean for a request's client to be null?

Tags: request, standards

The document [Fetch](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/) document states

> A request has an associated client (null or an environment settings
>   object).

What does it mean for a request's client to be null?

For example, if I run a `wget` at the command line, is the client for that request null? If I type in a URL in my browser's URL bar and hit ENTER, what is that request's client?

Comment: I don't think wget follows the whatwg fetch specs. Given a lot of specs do follow it though, it's quite hard to determine when this occurs. But for instance in *html*, it sounds like for simple [following of hyperlinks](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#following-hyperlinks-2), the request's client is initially null until it reaches *process-a-navigate-fetch* which will set it to `sourceBrowsingContext`. So it's a temporary state. Though it seems it's not clear [what the default client is](https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/907).

Answer (score 0):

That's a good question. [Section 5.2 of draft-ietf-httpbis-rfc6265bis-05](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-rfc6265bis-05#section-5.2) provides some answers. It describes one case in which a request's client is `"null"`.

> 1. If "request"'s client is "null", return "same-site".
>
>    Note that this is the case for navigation triggered by the user
>    directly (e.g. by typing directly into a user agent's address
>    bar).

Whether this is the only case in which a request's client is `"null"` is unclear to me, though.