# SameSite=Strict has no effect at all

Tags: cgi, setcookie, samesite

I would like to use a SameSite=Strict cookie to mitigate CSRF for GET-requests.
The cookie consists of a randomly generated string, and is set the following way:

```
"Set-Cookie: CSRF_TOKEN=random_string; Path=/; SameSite=Strict; Secure"
```

I'd expect the cookie not to be sent back to the server, if

1. I click a link embedded in a site on a different domain
2. I click a link somewhere else (e.g. in an email) which causes a new browser-tab to open
3. <strike>I paste the url to my site into the address bar of a new tab</strike> *(see comments)*

But all of the tests above failed, i.e. the cookie always got sent to the server.
Is this expected behavior?

NOTES:

- My page is accessed through its IPv4-address, no domain name is associated to it.
- I am using http basic authentication.
- I tested this in Google Chrome 96, Microsoft Edge 96 and Firefox 94.

Comment: I cannot reproduce either 1 or 2. As for 3, it's expected behaviour.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the note about 3, I now also found it in RFC6265bis:
>> If "request"'s client is "null", return "same-site". Note that this is the case for navigation triggered by the user directly (e.g. by typing directly into a user agent's address bar). <<

Comment: Yes, exactly. In case 3, the request's client is null. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59883012/what-does-it-mean-for-a-requests-client-to-be-null/65903255#65903255

Answer (score 0):

Regarding point 2, actually cookies are sent when SameSite is Strict and following a link in an Email, so long as the Email client is a standalone application and not browser-based.  If it is browser-based, it is a cross-domain link and blocked for that reason.  But following a link in an Email does count as a first-party request, ditto following a link in another application like Word.  I made a short [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/pvl5qA5E-pQ) demonstrating it as it does seem to cause confusion.

Regarding 1, that definitely should not result in the cookie being sent.  To confirm SameSite really is set to Strict on your cookie, open the browser's developer tools and look at your cookie and check the attribute is set as you expected.